# GLSL Shader r GL_INVALID_OPERATION from glUniform1f error with textureSize

Tags: shaders, glsl, vertex-shader

For debug purposes I've minimised the shader to the following:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    // ivec2 size = textureSize(u_texture, 0);//throws error if this line is enabled

    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

So don't mind what it actually does at the moment. With the line commented out it works fine, and other shaders work fine, but with the line in I get the errors:

`[GLProfiler] Error GL_INVALID_OPERATION from glUniform2f`

`[GLProfiler] Error GL_INVALID_OPERATION from glUniform1f`

`[GLProfiler] Error GL_INVALID_OPERATION from glUniformMatrix4fv`

Comment: Can you confirm which OpenGL version you're using? [If you're working in Godot and hitting limitations with GLES2, this thread may be of use](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/bokdyx/gles2_cant_use_texturesize/).

Comment: @DMGregory Yes that turned out to be the issue, too low a version of opengl in LibGDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because I'm using LibGDX and by default the opengl version is 2 which is not compatible with the function `textureSize`. A workaround is to input the texture size using a `uniform` variable.

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 resolution;//texture resolution is fed to the shader here


void main() {
    // ivec2 size = textureSize(u_texture, 0);//no need for this line

    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```